# How do I switch in/out of fullscreen mode from the command line in RealVNC?

Tags: vnc

How do I switch in/out of fullscreen mode from the command line in RealVNC?

This would be very handy, allowing me to keep my hands on the keyboard when I need to check my email (in Windows).

Answer (score 19):

Hit <kbd>F8</kbd> to pull up the menu and then select (using keyboard) the full screen toggle.

Comment: Thanks, but i have F8 mapped. Was hoping for something from the CLI. May have to go w/your suggestion if there's no suitable arg for `vncconfig` or the like.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to go off-path a little and answer this also for the [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/en/) fork [TigerVNC](http://tigervnc.org/), since they both have the same <kbd>F8</kbd> context-menu.

TigerVNC from v1.4.90 [onwards](https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/pull/120/commits/3c76a6d1eb6b375bdf973ff88988b12d12528bea) lets you type <kbd>F8</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> to toggle the full-screen state.  You will see other accelerator keys on that context menu too - <kbd>F8</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> to minimize the window is also helpful.  Nice and fast once you get used to it.

Comment: Worked. Is there a way to change this key-mapping? F8+F is not so easily reachable key combination, so want to assign different key combination for this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing Ctrl, Alt, Shift and F together should exit full screen mode.